# jQuery :How to Update function associted to a div object

Tags: jquery, binding

in jquery , how can i remove a function which is already  binded  to a div object (named divItem1) and bind a new function with new parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

[unbind](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/unbind)

> This does the opposite of bind, it
>   removes bound events from each of the
>   matched elements.
>
> Without any arguments, all bound
>   events are removed. If the type is
>   provided, all bound events of that
>   type are removed. If the function that
>   was passed to bind is provided as the
>   second argument, only that specific
>   event handler is removed.
>
> You can also unbind custom events
>   registered with bind.

If click event was bound to div with id 'divItem1' then you can use

```
$("#divItem1").unbind('click').bind('click' , function () { NewFunction(); } );
```

***Edit***

```
$("#divItem1").unbind('change').bind('change' , function () { NewFunction(param1, param2, ...); } );
```

Comment: how can i bind a function name with parameters . I have already a function definition on what to do on the change event

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select#foo').unbind('change').change(function() {
    something('param', 2)
});
```

[Reference](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/unbind)